# Let $\{f_n\}^∞_{n=1} ⊂ L_2(μ)$ be a sequence of functions such that $∥f_n∥_2 ≤ 1.$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Let $(X,A,μ)$ be a finite measure space. Let $\{f_n\}^∞_{n=1} ⊂ L_2(μ)$ be a sequence of functions such that $∥f_n∥_2 ≤ 1.$

a.) Prove that if $f_n → 0$ in measure, then $f_n → 0$ in $L_1(μ).$

b.) If $f_n → 0$ in measure, does it necessarily follow that $f_n → 0$ in $L_2(μ)?$

Not sure how to begin this problem.  Its from a past qual.  In particular I am at a loss at what to do with the $L_2$ condition.  Thanks for any help.

Comment: For a), use Hölder to show $(f_n)$ is uniformly integrable. Then use Vitali.

Comment: @DavidMitra Okay...so I showed that $(f_n)$ is uniformly integrable.  However, I do not see how to apply Vitali since $\mu(X)$ isn't necessarily finite and we do not necessarily have that $f_n$ goes to $f$ a.e.

Comment: $(X,A,\mu)$ is a finite measure space. Vitali holds for convergence in measure (every subsequence of $(f_n)$ has a subsequence converging a.e. to $f$; so every subsequence of $(f_n)$ has a subsequence converging in norm to $f$).

Comment: Ok thanks.  Sometimes I get confused between $\sigma-$finite measure and finite measure.

Answer (score 1):

For b), consider the following variant of the Vitali theorem. If $(X,A,\mu)$ is a finite measure space, then the statements "$f_n^p$ is uniformly integrable and $f_n \to f$ in measure" and "$f_n \to f$ in $L^p$" are equivalent. So you want to see whether these conditions imply that $f_n^2$ is uniformly integrable. If they do, prove it. If they don't, try and produce an example which is *not* uniformly integrable and also satisfies the boundedness hypothesis.

A more specific hint: if your condition were boundedness in $L^1$ instead of $L^2$, then $f_n(x) = n \chi_{[0,1/n]}$ would be a counterexample, since it converges in measure to 0 but the integrals are all 1. Can you adapt this to the setting of $L^2$?